# Getting [Object] from Coindesk API instead of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm using Nextjs and fetched the current price of a bitcoin from Coindesk's API:

`https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json`

I fetched the data in the `Home` component and in this component, I'm getting the correct json data. I'm sending this data to the `Prices` component as a prop but it's not logging correctly here in this component. Is there some issue with `axios`?

Instead of this: `bpi: { USD: {...}, GBP: {...}, EUR: {...} }`

I'm getting this: `bpi: { USD: [Object], GBP: [Object], EUR: [Object] }`

**Home.js**

```js
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import Prices from "../components/Prices"
import axios from "axios"

const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome to Bitzprice</h1>
        <Prices bpiData={props.bpiData} />
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

Home.getInitialProps = async function () {
  const res = await axios.get(
    "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
  ) 
  const data = res.data
  console.log("DATA=>", data)
  return {
    bpiData: data,
  }
}

export default Home
```

**Prices.js**

```js
class Prices extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currency: "USD",
  }

  render() {
    console.log("PROPS=>", this.props)
    return (
      <div>
        ....
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Prices
```

```js
DATA=> {
    time: {
      updated: 'Jul 26, 2020 10:29:00 UTC',
      updatedISO: '2020-07-26T10:29:00+00:00',
      updateduk: 'Jul 26, 2020 at 11:29 BST'
    },
    disclaimer: 'This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org',
    chartName: 'Bitcoin',
    bpi: {
      USD: {
        code: 'USD',
        symbol: '&#36;',
        rate: '9,983.2870',
        description: 'United States Dollar',
        rate_float: 9983.287
      },
      GBP: {
        code: 'GBP',
        symbol: '&pound;',
        rate: '7,804.6243',
        description: 'British Pound Sterling',
        rate_float: 7804.6243
      },
      EUR: {
        code: 'EUR',
        symbol: '&euro;',
        rate: '8,564.9015',
        description: 'Euro',
        rate_float: 8564.9015
      }
    }
  }
```

```js
PROPS=> {
  bpiData: {
    time: {
      updated: 'Jul 26, 2020 10:29:00 UTC',
      updatedISO: '2020-07-26T10:29:00+00:00',
      updateduk: 'Jul 26, 2020 at 11:29 BST'
    },
    disclaimer: 'This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org',
    chartName: 'Bitcoin',
    bpi: { USD: [Object], GBP: [Object], EUR: [Object] }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is probably correct, the [Object] is just a shortcut to avoid showing complicated nested object. If you do `console.log("DATA=>", JSON.stringify(data))`, you will have the full data.

Comment: `this.props.bpi` gives me undefined in `Prices.js`.

Comment: It's normal, it should be this.props.bpiData.bpi